# IE not loading css class - compiled with sass (scss file)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, visual-glitch

The class is added normally on the element, and in located in the appropriate scss file. It is applied naturally in all browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox, Edge) except IE (I tested only for IE11).

The class just doesn't appear to have any properties initially, in dev tools. But after an action is taken in the page, it is loaded. The problem is that it initially displays the page wrong, and the quick fix that I've applied is not a good one - timeout in js and remove & add class after a very short time. This makes for a glitchy initial experience with that page, in IE.

Has anybody else experienced this?
And if so, do you have a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

```
        // css here
        .container {
           width: 70%;
           margin: 0 auto!important;
           @media (max-width: 768px) {
              width: 100%;
           }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // script here
        function ieFixFunction() {
           if (/MSIE \d|Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
               document.querySelector(".project-dashboard  > div").classList.remove("container");
               setTimeout(function () { document.querySelector(".project-dashboard  > div").classList.add("container"); }, 0);
           }

        }
```

P.S.: I know that using **!important** is a big no-no

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either :(